# jQuery Ajax data not inserting into database

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a vote functionality on my page, where the page visitor is supposed to click a button, then that click is saved in the database. Nothing is being saved in the database though: Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.site-footer').hide();
    var counter;
    var id;

    jQuery('.fa-plus').click(function(){
        counter = 0;
        id      = jQuery(this).closest('div').prop("id");
        counter = counter+1;
        jQuery(this).css('color','green');
        jQuery(this).parent().html(counter);
        alert(name);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url    : "<?php  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>",
            type   : "POST",
            data   : {
                'action' : 'add_votes',
                'counter': counter,
                'id'     : id,
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my WordPress insert statement:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); 
function add_votes(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $votes= $_POST['counter'];
    if( !empty($_POST) ){
        global $wpdb;           
        $wpdb->insert(
            'fwwp_votes',
            array(
                'bride_id' => $id,
                'votes'    => $votes
            ),
            array(
                '%d',
                '%d'
            )
        );

    }   
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_add_votes', 'add_votes' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_votes', 'add_votes' );
```

Comment: Do you have any idea is Jquery not working or php ?

Comment: Well i added this in my PHP: `$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_POST));` and its returning the coreect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided the value for the `url` is wrong.
Wordpress gives us a unified file to use – wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. In Wordpress you must always use it's own unified file `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` to send request through AJAX.

Replace

```
url    : "<?php  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>",
```

To

```
url    : "<?php  echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
```

in `$.ajax()` parameters

Comment: Now when i do that, No data is being transmitted at all

Comment: look at your browser console for errors while clicking on `.fa-plus` button

Comment: I dont know if this is worth mentioning but all my jQuery and php are all on one page , and NOT a plugin

Comment: as you declared action as `wp_ajax_add_votes` you will need to use `<?php  echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>`  https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: and i have tested after changed action `url` to `<?php  echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>` , it storing data to db . @PamelaSillah

Comment: ok let me try it out. i suppose this means i have to put all my code in a plugin file?

Comment: that's okay , but you can also add to theme's functions.php file @PamelaSillah let me knw if it works for you

Comment: thank you @Govind. It worked Another issue worth mentioning is i had to move my php function `add_votes` to the functions.php file.